# Add at sign to Strings.xml

Tags: android

Is here a way how to add the at sign to `Strings.xml`? Neither `@` nor `&#64;` works. Do I really have to set it programmatically?

Comment: You want to add '@' sign to strings.xml?

Comment: I guess he want to add @ to a string in strings.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add '@' to  strings.xml then do it like this

```
<string name="at">\@</string>
```